# Where can I find a version of Qt designer to download for Linux?

Tags: qt

I would like to use Qt designer to edit my GUI applications,

But I can't find a URL to download!!

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?  QT Designer is likely included in its repositories.

Comment: I use Ubuntu10.10~

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be distro specific. In ubuntu you can download by typing in a command line or using synaptic search for qt-designer

> sudo apt-get install qt3-designer qt4-designer

Try googleing for the qt-designer rpm or deb to get a distribution specific download which will sort out dependencies for you.

Comment: Great Thks! It works!

Comment: @angela if some thing worked for you please let the community know by clicking the tick in the left under the up and down arrows. It says that this post answered you question.

Answer (score 1):

It's right there, on the official site. Go to http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/, choose the LGPL option and you'll see a list of available downloads. I think [**Qt SDK for Linux/X11 32-bit**](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/sdk-linux-x11-32bit-cpp) or [**Qt SDK for Linux/X11 64-bit**](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/sdk-linux-x11-64bit-cpp) will be what you want.

Comment: a lot of thks! I got it!